# Disable flash player in chrome via group policy

Tags: group-policy

How could I disable flash player in google chrome browsers for my 50 AD computers via group policy or script 2008 R2 ?
I have tried couple softwares, one of them - PDQDeploy_6, but this software is not suitable for my task.

Answer (score -1):

[How to disable flash player in google chrome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Caji3-dPEHY)